# Is this a Bug or a normal behavior ? Declaring procedure StubProc; cdecl; external xxx name 'TheHeadOfToto' not crash at compile time

Tags: ios, delphi

Under **delphi tokyo** and **iOS** I try to force to load a library by declaring a stub procedure like this :

```
procedure StubProc; cdecl; external '/usr/lib/clang/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a' name 'TheHeadOfToto';
```

But what disturb me (a little) is that even if `TheHeadOfToto` is not an existing function, this compile well, no error! This also force the load of the library at compile time (the behavior we want originally) !

But I was thinking that it's must crash and point me to something like a "typo" mistake instead! so is this a bug or normal behavior ?

Comment: It might perhaps not work properly (at **run**-time), but of course it should compile.

Answer (score 3):

It will compile fine, and run fine, so long as you just **declare** the function. The problem will arise if you attempt to **call** it. At that point you will encounter a runtime error because the function import cannot be resolved.

As an optimisation the compiler removes imports of functions that aren't called. Hence you only encounter an error for such erroneous imports if you actually attempt to call the function.